# @sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare. I get many error while run `npm run build`

Tags: deployment, devops, svelte, cloudflare-pages, webcrypto

I'm Using @sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare  to deploy my project to Cloudflare Pages.
I'm tried to use this package for a simple sveletKit app. It can success deploy to Pages.
But with more complex project, I got **many many ERROR** log while run build.

This is the **log**: https://pastebin.com/Yhw1Gu0c

And this is my **package.json**

```
    "name": "app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev --port 3331",
        "build": "vite build",
        "package": "svelte-kit package",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test": "playwright test",
        "check": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --check --plugin-search-dir=. . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write --plugin-search-dir=. ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@carbon/colors": "^11.3.0",
        "@firebase/app-types": "^0.7.0",
        "@playwright/test": "^1.22.2",
        "@solana/qr-code-styling": "1.6.0-beta.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "next",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare": "^1.0.0-next.31",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.27.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.27.0",
        "bignumber.js": "^9.0.2",
        "carbon-components-svelte": "^0.67.4",
        "carbon-icons-svelte": "^11.2.0",
        "carbon-preprocess-svelte": "^0.9.1",
        "cookie": "^0.5.0",
        "eslint": "^8.16.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
        "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.7.0",
        "sass": "^1.54.0",
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "svelte-check": "^2.7.1",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.6",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "typescript": "^4.7.4",
        "vite": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@solana/web3.js": "^1.50.1",
        "firebase": "^9.9.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73222998/14978104)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SvelteKit: Packages not being able to access node functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73178856/sveltekit-packages-not-being-able-to-access-node-functions)

Comment: Yes, this is answer my question.
In previous projects we often used Vercel's services. Maybe my friends used the old way for this project.

Comment: Although I'd like to find a way to deploy this project to Pages quickly. Instead of having to replace it with other packages

Comment: to deploy your project to Cloudflare Pages you'll have to follow [this guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#cloudflare-pages) (and then see [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#cloudflare-pages) for specifically cloudflare pages).

NB: Cloudflare Pages is a static site hosting platform. If your project needs to be dynamic you will have to choose a hosting provider that supports this

Comment: @henrygroves That's not true. Cloudflare Pages perfectly supports SSR. All server-side code, such as `+server.ts` files in the SvelteKit framework, are compiled into Cloudflare Workers which run directly at Cloudflare's backend, allowing you to quickly bind any other Cloudflare service such as D1s and KVs to variables with zero HTTP requests and use them directly in your server-side code. Thus you can perfectly achieve SSR by handling the `load` event inside `+page.server.ts` or build full backend APIs by handling the `GET/POST/...` of `+server.ts`'s. Other frameworks are also supported.